# Flatten a Dataframe within a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gitlab

I have this project where I pull a json from gitlab, filter its contents, and then spit out a csv report. I've been going in circles putting in different solutions, and I *did* get it to work on my personal PC using two different methods, but neither work in the gitlab environment.

First issue: The dataset I'm pulling is rather peculiar in that its 2d:

{'id':0, 'entity_type':'Project', 'details':{'author_name':'Billy', 'author_id':02}, 'created_at':10242022}

which translates to:

| id | entity_type | details | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Project | {'author_name':'Billy', 'author_id':02} | 10-24-2022 |

What I've been trying to do is flatten it into this:

| id | entity_type | author_name | author_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Project | 'Billy' | 02 | 10-24-2022 |

What I have so far is the following, which works on my personal PC, but for some reason not the gitlab:

```
import pandas as pd

#pull data from the gitlab
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
sub_df = df.details.apply(pd.Series)    #pull out details column
sub_df = pd.concat({'details':sub_df}, axis=1, names=['l1','l2'])    #
df = pd.concat({'':df}, axis=1, names =['l1','l2'])
df = pd.concat((df, sub_df), axis=1)

#code to delete unnecessary data from df.
```

Now, on my PC when I run this code, pd.Series helps turn the 'details' column into multiple columns of the headers within. However, when I run it on the GitLab, it instead separates into multiple columns of 'details' with each value stored underneath, ie:

| details | details | details | details | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| author_name | Billy | author_id | 02 | ... |
| author_name | Sam | author_id | 05 | ... |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `json_normalize` instead of `apply(pd.Series)`

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df.pop('details'))], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a list of dictionaries as data. I would suggest that you flatten the dictionaries (in the list of dictionaries) before converting it into a `DataFrame`.

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming this is how your data looks:
data = [
    {
        'id':0,
        'entity_type':'Project',
        'details':{'author_name':'Billy','author_id':'02'},
        'created_at':10242022
    },
    {
        'id':1,
        'entity_type':'Project',
        'details':{'author_name':'Sam','author_id':'05'},
        'created_at':10242022
    }
]

flattened_data = [dict(d, **d.pop("details")) for d in data]

df = pd.DataFrame(flattened_data)

df.head()
```

which results in this:

|  | id | entity_type | author_name | author_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Project | Billy | 02 | 10242022 |
| 1 | 1 | Project | Sam | 05 | 10242022 |

Comment: Doesn't seem to want to work as the gitlab ide keeps wanting to recognize the data as a string instead of as a dictionary. I've tried reading it as a json, changing its type using ast.literal_eval(), and even trying to break it down further by converting the column into other types. All to no avail.